# Passing context to RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android

I've just started learning android programming and I'm trying to load Urls from an RSS feed into my recycler view (which I've done). The next task I've set myself is to load the images from the RSS feed into the RecyclerView but I'm having issues getting my head around trying to pass a context the Picasso plugin (http://square.github.io/picasso/) , or even why this/getContext/getApplicationContext doesnt work.

Here is my adapter code with the line for the Picasso plugin.

Any help / understanding would be appreciated.

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ApplicationViewHolder> {


public static class ApplicationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    TextView personReleasedate;
    ImageView imageUrl;

    ApplicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personReleasedate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.personReleaseDate);
        imageUrl = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImageView);
    }
}

List<Application> applications;

RVAdapter(List<Application> applications) {
    this.applications = applications;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public ApplicationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardviewrss, viewGroup, false);
    ApplicationViewHolder pvh = new ApplicationViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ApplicationViewHolder applicationViewHolder, int i) {
    applicationViewHolder.personName.setText(applications.get(i).getName());
    applicationViewHolder.personAge.setText(applications.get(i).getArtist());
    applicationViewHolder.personReleasedate.setText(applications.get(i).getReleaseDate());
    Log.d("RVADAPTER", applications.get(i).getImageURL());
    Picasso.with(this).load(applications.get(i).getImageURL()).into(applicationViewHolder.imageUrl);
  //  applicationViewHolder.imageUrl.setImageBitmap(Picasso.with(context).load(applications.get(i).getImageURL()));
```

//      applicationViewHolder.imageUrl.setText(applications.get(i).getImageURL());

```
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return applications.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Solved by passing context through the constructor. Sorry to waste anyone's time !

Comment: You could also avoid the dependency by just grabbing the context from the view (e.g. `applicationViewHolder.itemView.getContext()`)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
List<Application> applications;
Context context;

RVAdapter(List<Application> applications, Context context) {
    this.applications = applications;
    this.context = context;
}
```

and pass it from activity/fragment?